# How to add a Site column of type "Managed Metadata"to a SharePoint 2010 List with c#

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata, site-column

I would like to know if is that possible to add a Site column of type "Managed Metadata" to a SharePoint 2010 List with c#

Thanks a lot for your help

Regards,

Arioule

Comment: check this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2012/04/16/programmatically-create-a-managed-metadata-list-column-mohammed-faizan.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It depends what [API is used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060(v=office.15).aspx):

SSOM

- [SPFieldCollection.Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472869(v=office.15).aspx) - creates a field in the collection
  based on the specified display name, field type, and Boolean value
- [SPFieldCollection.AddFieldAsXml method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457586(v=office.15).aspx) - creates a field based
  on the specified schema

CSOM

- [FieldCollection.AddFieldAsXml method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldcollection.addfieldasxml.aspx) - creates a field based on
  the specified schema, Boolean value, and field options

### How to provision Managed Metadata column via CSOM

Assume the following taxonomy field schema:

```
<Field Type="TaxonomyFieldType" DisplayName="Country"  ShowField="Term1033" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Group="Custom Columns" ID="{474eb740-64bc-40bd-a177-7f7cf9fa8ed5}" SourceID="{6dfea1bb-6a93-4d49-a8cd-7e797716a8e5}" StaticName="Country" Name="Country">
  <Default></Default>
  <Customization>
    <ArrayOfProperty>
      <Property>
        <Name>SspId</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q1:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">b5b6effd-4925-43e4-ad43-a257213dedec</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>GroupId</Name>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>TermSetId</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q2:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">b95498b8-600b-4b02-a467-8b6f91823658</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>AnchorId</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q3:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>UserCreated</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q4:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>Open</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q5:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>TextField</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q6:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{708a33d8-ef52-4e61-b8ca-cfd91a0f2dae}</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>IsPathRendered</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q7="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q7:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>IsKeyword</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q8="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q8:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>TargetTemplate</Name>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>CreateValuesInEditForm</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q9="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q9:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>FilterAssemblyStrongName</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q10="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q10:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>FilterClassName</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q11="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q11:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>FilterMethodName</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q12="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q12:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">GetFilteringHtml</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>FilterJavascriptProperty</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q13="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q13:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">FilteringJavascript</Value>
      </Property>
    </ArrayOfProperty>
  </Customization>
</Field>
```

Then the following example demonstrates how to provision field using [FieldCollection.AddFieldAsXml method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldcollection.addfieldasxml.aspx):

```
public static void ProvisionField(ClientContext ctx,string listTitle, string fieldSchema)
{
    var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var field = list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(fieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
    field.Update();
    ctx.Load(field);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Usage

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    ctx.Credentials = credentials;
    ProvisionField(ctx,listTitle,fieldSchema);    
}
```